# c gtk+-2:can't see buttons that are added to GtkHButtonBox

Tags: c, gtk, glade

I'm trying to create a simple program that fetches a GtkHButtonBox from a glade file, adds a button to it and displays the entire window. the problem is that I can't see any buttons that I add and i didn't see any warnings errors or assertions.

this is my main.c file:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <gtk/gtk.h>


GtkBuilder *builder;


#define UI_FILE "gtk_hbuttonbox.ui"


int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
GtkWidget *window,*box, *button;


gtk_set_locale ();
gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
GError* error = NULL;

builder = gtk_builder_new ();
if (!gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, UI_FILE, &error))
{
    g_warning ("Couldn't load builder file: %s", error->message);
    g_error_free (error);
}

/* This is important */
window = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window"));
box = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "hbuttonbox1"));

g_object_unref (builder);

button = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_button_new_with_label ("moshe"));

gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX(box),button,FALSE,FALSE,0);

gtk_widget_show (button);
gtk_widget_show (window);

gtk_main ();
return 0;
}
```

this is my gtk_hbuttonbox.ui glade file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="2.16"/>
  <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">window</property>
    <property name="default_width">500</property>
    <property name="default_height">400</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="destroy" object="NULL"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkHButtonBox" id="hbuttonbox1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

using gtk+ 2.22.1 and glade 3.6.7

any ideas how to resolve the issue ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe just missing gtk_widget_show(button) ?

Comment: unfortunately after adding gtk_widget_show(button) the results are the same.

Comment: I cut-and-pasted your code above, added #include <gtk/gtk.h>, replaced UI_FILE with my local filename, and I saw a window with a button labeled "moshe" in it. perhaps the problem is something other than the code pasted here.

Comment: welp i tested it again on a different computer and the gtk_widget_show is the proper solution for my question. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
gtk_widget_show (button);
gtk_widget_show (window);
```

use:

```
gtk_widget_show_all (window);
```

This will show the main window and all its child widgets.